# How to align multiple div's when there's multiple lines of text above it

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want the div that's containing the 3 social icons to align at the bottom with the same div in the right tile. But the social icons div on the right is pushed down because there's 2 lines of text above it while on the left one its just one line. How could I fix this?

[image]

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c6torbvz/) and snippet that reproduces my problem:

```css
.fh5co-gallery {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.fh5co-gallery .gallery-item .overlay h2,
.fh5co-gallery .gallery-item .overlay span {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 12;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  -o-transition: 0.5s;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.fh5co-gallery .gallery-item {
  width: 33%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  z-index: 110;
}

.fh5co-gallery .gallery-item img {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: 0.9s;
  -o-transition: 0.9s;
  transition: 0.9s;
}

.fh5co-gallery .gallery-item .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 11;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-top: 18%;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  -o-transition: 0.5s;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

#social_icons {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="fh5co-gallery">
  <div style="width:33.33%" class="gallery-item" href="#">

    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/410">

    <span class="overlay">
        <h2>test test test test test test test</h2>
        <span>test</span> <br>
    <div id="social_icons" style="text-align:center;">
      <span style="display:inline-block;">1</span>
      <span style="display:inline-block;">2</span>
      <span style="display:inline-block;">3</span>
    </div>
    </span>

  </div>
  <div style="width:33.33%" class="gallery-item" href="#">

    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/410">

    <span class="overlay">
        <h2>bedankt</h2>
        <span>test</span> <br>
    <div id="social_icons">
      <span style="display:inline-block;">1</span>
      <span style="display:inline-block;">2</span>
      <span style="display:inline-block;">3</span>
    </div>
    </span>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: could you please create a sample fiddle or snippet that reproduces your problem...

Comment: Please create a [mcve] demonstrating your current problem

Comment: Use a table, [grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) or [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) layout. Follow the links, pretty good tutorials available.

Comment: @kukkuz https://jsfiddle.net/c6torbvz/ hope this helps. thanks

Comment: @Pete https://jsfiddle.net/c6torbvz/ hope this helps

Comment: @kerv please use the snippet button and enter the code in the question itself, otherwise this question is off topic: 1.Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: @Pete I cant just add all the code from the fiddle into the question right? that would be way to much, I dont understand how my question is off topic. its a css related question. I have added the desired behaviour in means of using screenshots and describing how i want it, the screenshot is also showing the specific problem and now I have sent you a fiddle with the code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is a repository of information for future visitors.  If the fiddle link dies, then there is no information on this page showing your actual issue in code, that is why your question is off topic.  And I have added much more code than that into a question before.  Anyway, now you have added a fiddle, you will probably get some rep grabber answering this

Comment: @kerv have edited the answer for you, its always good to add a *snippet* for the reasons now you know about :)

Comment: @kukkuz thanks! appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a *column* flexbox in `.fh5co-gallery .gallery-item .overlay` and use `margin-top: auto` and use `margin-bottom` to adjust the position of the `social_icons` - see demo below and [`fiddle here`](https://jsfiddle.net/fp1wL46v/):

```css
.fh5co-gallery {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.fh5co-gallery .gallery-item .overlay h2,
.fh5co-gallery .gallery-item .overlay span {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 12;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  -o-transition: 0.5s;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.fh5co-gallery .gallery-item {
  width: 33%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  z-index: 110;
}

.fh5co-gallery .gallery-item img {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: 0.9s;
  -o-transition: 0.9s;
  transition: 0.9s;
}

.fh5co-gallery .gallery-item .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 11;
  display: flex; /* ADDED*/
  flex-direction: column; /* ADDED*/
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-top: 18%;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  -o-transition: 0.5s;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

#social_icons {
  text-align: center;
  /* margin-top: 30px; */
  margin-top: auto; /* ADDED*/
  margin-bottom: 30px; /* adjust this value */
}
```

```html
<div class="fh5co-gallery">
  <div style="width:33.33%" class="gallery-item" href="#">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/410">
    <span class="overlay">
        <h2>test test test test test test test</h2>
        <span>test</span> <br>
    <div id="social_icons" style="text-align:center;">
      <span style="display:inline-block;">1</span>
      <span style="display:inline-block;">2</span>
      <span style="display:inline-block;">3</span>
    </div>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div style="width:33.33%" class="gallery-item" href="#">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/410">
    <span class="overlay">
        <h2>bedankt</h2>
        <span>test</span> <br>
    <div id="social_icons">
      <span style="display:inline-block;">1</span>
      <span style="display:inline-block;">2</span>
      <span style="display:inline-block;">3</span>
    </div>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```